# Why does np.select not allow me to put in index above total length into choicelist?

Tags: python, pandas, numpy

I am trying to get the first value of the the list in each row of df['Emails'] but in real life (this is a sample df) I don't know what the length of the list will be so I am just assuming that the longest will be length of 5 and then trying to whittle it down until I find the right length and selecting that index position but I am getting `IndexError: index 5 is out of bounds for axis 0 with size 2` and I can't figure out what to do about it. Any help appreciated. Thanks.

my current code:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'Emails': [['j@gmail.com', 'jp@gmail.com', 'jc@gmail.com'],[None, 'jzp@gmail.com']],
                   'num_wings': [2, 0],
                   'num_specimen_seen': [10, 2]},
                  index=['falcon', 'dog'])
df['Emails'] = np.select([df['Emails'][0],df['Emails'][1],df['Emails'][2]],[df['Emails'][0],df['Emails'][1],df['Emails'][2]])
print(data['Emails'])
```

Expected output:

Assuming the original dataframe has `None` in the first index position I want it to take the next index position that isn't `None`

Desired Output

```
              Emails  num_wings  num_specimen_seen
falcon   j@gmail.com          2                 10
dog     jzp@gmail.com          0                  2
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Whenever you have a column containing lists, `explode` will often be your friend, and this is the case here.

Use `explode`, `groupby(level=0)` (to group on the 0th (first) level of the index), and `first` (which selects the first non-null value (including None, NaN, etc.))

```
df['Emails'] = df['Emails'].explode().groupby(level=0).first()
```

Output:

```
>>> df
               Emails  num_wings  num_specimen_seen
falcon    j@gmail.com          2                 10
dog     jzp@gmail.com          0                  2
```

Comment: that is extremely helpful to know! I keep running into this issue so knowing that it’s better to just explode each to its own row then apply groupby to it makes a lot of sense! Thank you so much!

Comment: You're welcome! Yes, `explode` I think might be my favorite pandas function. It's just so useful! Note that if you want to condense the explosion back into lists, `df['col'].explode().groupby(level=0).agg(list)`.